# Why am I getting a 'TypeError: undefined is not a function' here?

Tags: node.js, typescript, commonjs, typescript1.5

I am running into a strange (to me) error when trying to run the code specified below. The code compiles fine, but when I run it, node returns this error:

```
<location>/C.js:11
    _super.call(this, "C");
           ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at new C (<location>/C.js:11:16)
    at Function.B.factory (<location>/B.js:15:17)
    at Function.Test.test (<location>/Test.js:6:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (<location>/app.js:2:6)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
```

**Compile command**: tsc --module commonjs -t ES5 app.ts

**Run with**: node app.js

Obviously I am new to both Typescript and Javascript, but I just can't see why this would fail. I have looked around for a solution but although this seems to be a common issue, I have come up empty for my particular problem. Can anyone shed some light on as to why this is happening? Here are the files:

**A.ts**

```
class A {
    constructor(private name: string) {}
}
export = A;
```

**B.ts**

```
import A = require('./A');
import C = require('./C');

class B extends A {
    constructor(value: string) {
        super(value);
    }
    public static factory() {
        var a: A = new C();
        return a;
    }
}
export = B;
```

**C.ts**

```
import B = require('./B');

class C extends B {
    constructor() {
        super("C");
    }
}
export = C;
```

**Test.ts**

```
import B = require('./B');

class Test {
    public static test() {
        return B.factory();
    }
}
export = Test;
```

**app.ts**

```
///<reference path='./typings/node/node.d.ts' />
import Test = require('./Test');
Test.test();
```

In order to save some space here, I pastebinned the generated javascript code. It can be found here if you're interested: [javascript dump](http://pastebin.com/Dg8QaLUL)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you have a circular dependency. `C` depends on `B` and `B` depends on `C`. Therefore `B` is undefined according to spec. https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_cycles

Comment: So I can't use this kind of factory pattern when using Node then? That is rather disappointing. Thank you a lot for the clear answer!

Comment: Solution is to move the interdependent files into a *single file*. This is the general solution even in the browser.

Comment: I am trying to avoid that since I suspect it will be a large PITA to maintain as the project grows.

Comment: Not all files. Just these two that have a cycle

Comment: Ok, thank you! I will upvote your answer once I acquire enough points.

Comment: There are other solutions as well. 1) The factory usually does **not needs to extend** the base class, it can be another class (as here: https://www.bezkoder.com/node-js-factory-pattern/)

Comment: 2) Use [decorator pattern](https://blog.logrocket.com/design-patterns-in-node-js-2/) instead of inheritance. As here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44134469/typescript-nodejs-circular-dependency-while-working-with-factories